# How to go to next column within a loop in tsql

Tags: database, t-sql, while-loop, cursor

Suppose a table has 5 columns, and starting from the first column, you want to iterate through every column and fill it with data, til the last. Im having trouble hard coding the specific column name because im using a loop, my attempt so far is trying to set a created string the same name as the next column based on the counter value.. It's not going my way, now im stuck at the first column which gets overwritten each loop.. Is this possible to solve in tsql?

```
FETCH NEXT FROM ZipZap_Cursor into @XX, @ZZ

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0 and @Counter <= 4)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @StaffingGrid
            SET COLUMN_1 = CONCAT(@XX, '/', @ZZ) // THEN COLUMN_2, THEN COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4..
            WHERE ENAMN = 'Last Name'
            SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1

            FETCH NEXT FROM ZipZap_Cursor into @XX, @ZZ
        END
```

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyb17.png)

Comment: Cursors move through rows, not columns, You'll need _dynamic SQL_ if you want to generate column names on-the-fly. A clumsier solution is possible, e.g. using a `case` expression for each column, if all of the column names are known in advance. This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: thank you my good sir, will check both type of solutions out immediately

Comment: Im not using the cursor for this specific task here, don't mind my cursor

Comment: What database platform are you using? A number of databases support the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) views. In SQL Server, your query would look like this. `SELECT * FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableNameGoesHere'` You could then iterate through your columns in a cursor.